# Econtrando problema conexão de banco com Visual Studio

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012

Olá, alguém sabe se tem alguma forma de encontrar código problemático em c# relacionado à abertura e fechamento de conexões com banco de dados? Tenho uma aplicação que depois de algumas horas processando uma carga ao executar um select gera um erro de idle time(ORA-02396)

Mas olhando as estruturas não consegui identificar problema no código na linha onde é informado o erro:

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(banco))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 500;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                foreach (OracleParameter op in parametros)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(op);
                }

                con.Open();
                DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
                using (OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    tabela.Load(odr);
                }

                return tabela;
            }
        }
```

Ao executar uma query no banco para capturar os user_resource_limit, o IDLE_TIME do Oracle estava em 30. O problema é que preciso buscar uma solução no código para o problema sem precisar solicitar a mudança deste parâmetro. Queria saber se existe uma espécie de profiler nativo do Visual Studio 2012 para ajudar a localizar pontos de "vazamento".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O VS 2012 possui profile nativo:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Com ele é possível analisar gráfico de perfomance, custo das execuções dos métodos, entre outras métricas.

Você precisará deste patch do VS 2012 para conseguir analisar os reports gerados:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40776

Comment: Opa, exatamente o que eu preciso, vai ajudar bastante. Obrigado Jaspion